# web music player at 1.5x/2x speed

Tags: web-applications, web, html5-audio

I'm gonna develop a web app that plays audio. I would like it to play music at 1x/1.5x/2x or any other speed with respect to the users' needs. However, it seems that the embedded html sound element has only a play/pause button. I'm not sure if I can do the play/speed up using other tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe my question does not clarify my needs clearly. However, i've found a simple solution to my question.

The link below seems to be a good reference.

[HTML Audio and Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)